# Вывод элементов двумерного массива построчно через запятую

Tags: python

Размерность квадратной матрицы вводится с клавиатуры (size). Генерируется матрица, у которой в строке содержатся первые size натуральных чисел (начиная с 1).

```
n = int(input())
mas = []
for i in range(0, n, 1):
    mas.append([])
    for j in range(1, n+1, 1):
        mas[i].append(j)

tmas = [*zip(*mas)]
index = 0
for row in mas:
    for elem in row:
        print(elem, end=', ')
    print()
```

Пытаюсь вывести двумерный массив вот так:

```
1, 2, 3, 4  
1, 2, 3, 4  
1, 2, 3, 4  
1, 2, 3, 4
```

а выводится вот так:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4,
```

Как исправит?

Comment: вместо  `end=', '`  используйте  `sep=','`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто выводить построчно, а не поэлементно.

```
n = 4
mas = [list(range(1,n+1)) for _ in range(n)]
for row in mas:
    print(*row, sep=', ')
```